# Model Key Path With Multiple Properties

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, kvc

Here, I'm using an `NSArrayController` to bind properties from Core Data entities into the value of text view table cells.

[image]

What syntax do I use to access multiple properties of the entity in the Model Key Path?

Example as a format string: `@"%@, %@", lastName, firstName;`

Comment: What does this have to do with iOS?

Comment: Haha, force of habit, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the bindings inspector for the text field:

1. Select "Value With Pattern: Display Pattern Value1"
2. Bind to the array controller
3. Controller key = `selection`
4. Model key path = `lastName`
5. Display pattern = `%{value1}@, %{value2}@`
6. Select the now available in bindings inspector: "Display Pattern Value2"
7. Bind Value2 to AC, `selection`, `firstName`

This is documented in the [NSTextField section of the Cocoa Bindings Reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTextField-SW1)

For completeness, here is some of my own code where I do this sort of binding programmatically:

```
NSString* bannerPattern = @": %{value1}@ items found, %{value2}@ hidden %{value3}@";
NSString* totalPattern = [dateString stringByAppendingString:bannerPattern];

[ftview.textField bind:@"displayPatternValue1" toObject:ft withKeyPath:@"visibleNumber" options:@{NSDisplayPatternBindingOption : totalPattern}];
[ftview.textField bind:@"displayPatternValue2" toObject:ft withKeyPath:@"hiddenNumber" options:@{NSDisplayPatternBindingOption : totalPattern}];
[ftview.textField bind:@"displayPatternValue3" toObject:ft withKeyPath:@"newString" options:@{NSDisplayPatternBindingOption : totalPattern}];
```